# SQLAlchemy relationship cascade deletion

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have read the documentation, but I still can't seem to understand exactly how to configure my models properly. It's a very simple TV show database and I want to configure it so that an Episode *must* have a corresponding Show parent instance to exist in the database. Whenever a Show is deleted, I want all of its episodes to be cascade deleted.

TL;DR: show.delete() --> all episodes ep where ep.show_id == show.id are deleted

How do I accomplish this?

```
class Show(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)

class Episode(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)

    # relationships
    show_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('show.id'), nullable=False)
    show = db.relationship('Show',
                           backref=db.backref('episodes'),
                           lazy='joined')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [cascades](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html?highlight=relationship#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.cascade):

```
    show = db.relationship('Show',
                           backref=db.backref('episodes', cascade="all, delete-orphan"),
                           lazy='joined')
```

Comment: I've seen people use `ondelete="CASCADE"`, how does that relate to my problem?

Comment: the mentioned option makes the database cascade deletes while the `cascade` option makes the client organize the deletes. I suggest you read up on your database (for capabilities) and the SQLA docs, if you want to consider that way. The `cascade` way is more fine-grained, but the `ondelete` way *might* be interesting as well.